# Creating common gateway for Azure network

Tags: azure, gateway, azure-networking

Suppose I created a Linux VM instance on Azure (Let's call it A1). To access this instance from my company's network I had to ask the IT team to allow the outbound traffic from my company's machine (Let's call it C1) to A1 on a certain port of A1, say 22 for SSH. Due to the long hierarchy of my company, the IT team usually takes 3-5 business days to reconfigure the firewall to allow this traffic.

Currently, my team is in a process of developing some PoCs which might require us to access a number of instances( the number is not yet decided) and that too to different ports of these instances. Asking IT team to allow access to all these instances and then waiting 3-5 days for each of them would really drop the rate of our productivity so I decided to create some sort of common gateway on Azure for which I'd ask the IT team to provide access to and which in turn will forward my traffic to appropriate instance.

Since I do not have much experience with creating such networks, I wanted to ask the experts here about the right approach to do so. What is the industrial practice in such circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a virtual network gateway in Azure and use point-to-site VPN to connect to Azure virtual network. Another thing you can do is just use the existing linux server as a jump box. Connect to it and connect further or forward port.

reading:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about
https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example

Answer (score 1):

A virtual network gateway and VPN is the best route to take here. It would allow you easily scale up to dozens or hundreds of Azure machines with only a single or small number of rules.

You should really **not** consider doing any kind of port forwarding through your A1 box, at least without express permission. Depending on how your business has it's usage policy is written it could be grounds for termination.

Playing ball with your network team can be slow but it is important to do, especially since this does include a network change.

Comment: why being so drammatic? nothing wrong with using a jumpbox\bastion host.

Comment: @4c74356b41 - I agree, but tunneling services without permission is often expressly against acceptable use policies.

Comment: this question is not about security\network policies, so not sure why you bring this up. I can say something: "my company is not allowed to use public clouds, so you shouldn't use Azure". This has nothing to do with the question.